# Parse JSON Data in Android Nullpointer exception

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception, google-play-services, google-places-api

I am developing an Android application which will display the nearby restaurants.
I am making the request to get the nearby restaurants but when I try to parse the JSONObject i just get a NullpointerException. Does anybody have any idea why ?

This is part of my response which I try to parse:

```
 {
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "CpQCAgEAAACxlIhK4r2DmgCitXEHpZ_f4LeYyjKty-1BZRJUlgnP0Mxh-dkNB2PSUjtXAkuFwLzDr-aFeNaK4PSsSS0jrQY6-rJWCElila7wDae29ahnwfyVZtaaUPWYvpDidVMuVphL60Ya5I0ZT9ANWsMPUScNad3NpTj3DwEcMZ8pO9VQWL5eyi-gjBgATRMzYecqAvHVM7pl5TuARK_NXe4H7QQKA_75DoxPqvPA8QP_eSho-jchGgvrHzYP2PNJc5uThDEIFLIAPlKLA_x9gJDMZDV9P5LPUU9do5PubLjzdFoesb8H9wbmmG9XOkqdKZO_z8j8hYcesBmVlLEEwOLLkUKfjd0ZWtK0NHjViax5wU6IEhC-WDuSs1J6iItu_zhjJ7NmGhSN-LfQXEVngBRXp8yAiVLovLpHRA",
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 45.7685383,
               "lng" : 21.2359562
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 45.76859194999999,
                  "lng" : 21.23602585
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 45.76837735,
                  "lng" : 21.23574724999999
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging-71.png",
         "id" : "412f1d9eb7bed393635e0ab7bf8466cc93aa6ccc",
         "name" : "Hotel Angellis",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 2268,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116657895353294198181/photos\"\u003eBogdan Blendea\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAALIMEHpH8s_o2gRH2tt_nFNpNCjfWeKGaIa9mK3I6Y0a_xq-ollc1k3IWfl22n7K6fVGUaoAKEcRWjnibFT2GDQIvuUeYztxAvlMU_OjW_UnvSGzlSFp2UjVx0Xgk0LhstOYjOvCRYRRqfwJsMnKxS7PJLeCx439krcJs_-y-Zw9EhBunXXIoGXQW2dEpQgc-OOJGhSf4fHczYm-ZGsbk6sYECJ8KT4Ofg",
               "width" : 4032
            }
         ]
```

This is how I am trying to parse my jsonobject:

```
package com.upt.cti.nearbyrestaurant;

import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Alex on 11/20/2016.
 */

public class DataParser {
    public List<HashMap<String, String>> parse(String jsonData) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        JSONObject jsonObject;

        try {
            Log.d("Places", "parse");
            jsonObject = new JSONObject((String)jsonData);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("Places", "parse error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return getPlaces(jsonArray);
    }

    private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        int placesCount = jsonArray.length();
        List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, String> placeMap = null;
        Log.d("Places", "getPlaces");

        for (int i = 0; i < placesCount; i++) {
            try {
                placeMap = getPlace((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i));
                placesList.add(placeMap);
                Log.d("Places", "Adding places");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("Places", "Error in Adding places");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return placesList;
    }

    private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject googlePlaceJson) {
        HashMap<String, String> googlePlaceMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String placeName = "-NA-";
        String vicinity = "-NA-";
        String latitude = "";
        String longitude = "";
        String reference = "";

        Log.d("getPlace", "Entered");

        try {
            if (!googlePlaceJson.isNull("name")) {
                placeName = googlePlaceJson.getString("name");
            }
            if (!googlePlaceJson.isNull("vicinity")) {
                vicinity = googlePlaceJson.getString("vicinity");
            }
            latitude = googlePlaceJson.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
            longitude = googlePlaceJson.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");
            reference = googlePlaceJson.getString("reference");
            googlePlaceMap.put("place_name", placeName);
            googlePlaceMap.put("vicinity", vicinity);
            googlePlaceMap.put("lat", latitude);
            googlePlaceMap.put("lng", longitude);
            googlePlaceMap.put("reference", reference);
            Log.d("getPlace", "Putting Places");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("getPlace", "Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return googlePlaceMap;
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
                                                                                at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
                                                                                at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
                                                                                at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
                                                                                at com.upt.cti.nearbyrestaurant.DataParser.parse(DataParser.java:25)
                                                                                at com.upt.cti.nearbyrestaurant.GetNearbyPlacesData.onPostExecute(GetNearbyPlacesData.java:45)
                                                                                at com.upt.cti.nearbyrestaurant.GetNearbyPlacesData.onPostExecute(GetNearbyPlacesData.java:19)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Why not using just `new JSONObject(jsonData)` instead of `new JSONObject((String)jsonData)` ?

Comment: thumbs up. Thanks @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: What String are you passing in to your jsonData variable here? jsonObject = new JSONObject((String)jsonData);